# Convert excel table to key list

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I want to create a key list for a large hdf file from an Excel file:

Table:

[image]

I want the key list to look like this:

```
/blue/a/a1
/blue/a/a2
/blue/b/b1
...
```

my code so far is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', usecols = ['A', 'B', 'C'])
print(df)


list1, list2, list3 = df['A'].tolist(), df['B'].tolist(), df['C'].tolist()
print(list1,list2,list3)

for i in list1:
    list1[i].append(list2[i]).append(list3[i])


print(list1)
```

The conversion to 3 lists works. Then I try to append the rows of each list together, without success. Is there a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zip` method and then use `string.join` to get your required output

**Ex:**

```
res = []
list1, list2, list3 = df['A'].tolist(), df['B'].tolist(), df['C'].tolist()
for i in zip(list1, list2, list3 ):
    val = map(str, i)
    res.append("/{0}".format("/".join(val)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately I am getting an error.
TypeError: sequence item 2: expected str instance, float found.

The table has a few NaN, could it result in the error?

Comment: Your code works with the table I provided. Unfortunately it doesnt with the table I am working with and I do not know why. The rows look like this: blue;AGHZTG;M227

Comment: How about converting the elements to str. `val = map(str, i)  res.append("/{0}".format("/".join(val)))`

Answer (score 1):

You should use a apply function to create a new column as required and then convert it to a list

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', usecols = ['A', 'B', 'C'])
print(df)
x=df[['A','B','C']].apply(lambda row: '/'+row['A']+'/'+row['B']+'/'+row['C'],axis=1)
x.tolist()
```

Update shorter code:

```
x=df[['A','B','C']].apply(lambda row: '/'+'/'.join(row),axis=1)
x.tolist()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This Looks like an elegant solution, unfortunately I am getting a KeyError('A','B','C')

Comment: You might need to change the axis to 1

Comment: Still getting the same Error